# Symfony 4 Doctrine relations , collections dont get datas

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine, foreign-keys

**First of all, excuse my bad english.**

> I'm using Symfony 4.0 with Doctrine-bridge 4.0. When using a OneToMany
>   relation, the property remains empty.

### Context

> I'm trying to create a user entity and a bank account entity so that
>   only account that are currently afillied to this user are able to be
>   load by the user entity.
>
> I've created an User entity with a OneToMany relation to an Account
>   entity. The Account has a (inverse) ManyToOne relation to User. When I
>   call $user I get an empty collection in my relation's field.

### Expected result

> When dump $user I expect to get a collection of the
>   Accounts entities that are currently stored in $user accounts field and match the database with my
>   user_id.

### Actual result

An empty collection is returned

```
   User {#399 ▼
  -uid: 1
  -name: "Elie"
  -lastname: "XXXXX"
  -birthdate: DateTime @821919600 {#410 ▶}
  -email: "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xx"
  -password: "$2y$13$QAdyMal7VZmXzR3IwCFHYeDKokW0bRqko5rZHPtnhrbncdVVAr7E."
  -salt: null
  -roles: "ROLE_ADMIN"
  -username: "Elie"
  -accounts: PersistentCollection {#256 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: User {#399}
    -association: array:16 [ …16]
    -em: EntityManager {#213 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "user"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#401 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: ArrayCollection {#419 ▼
      -elements: []
    }
    #initialized: false
  }
}
```

### Other infos

Searching on Doctrine @OneToMany gives me people that have forgotten some parameters, arguments etc. or made a typo. I can't find one of those in my code. So I'm kind of stuck. Please Help.

**User entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="APP_USERS")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
 class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable 
 {

    ...

    **
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", indexBy="user", mappedBy="user")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account", referencedColumnName="user")
    */
    private $accounts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accounts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * @return Collection|Account[]
    */
    public function getAccounts()
    {
        return $this->accounts;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $accounts
     */
    public function setAccounts($accounts): void
    {
        $this->accounts = $accounts;
    }
```

**Account entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="APP_ACCOUNTS")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AccountRepository")
 */
 class Account
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="accounts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, unique=false, referencedColumnName="uid")
     */
     private $user;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
     public function setUser($user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

Comment: It would be good to share the whole code of both entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying "EAGER" fetching to avoid lazy loading.

```
**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", indexBy="user", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account", referencedColumnName="user")
*/
private $accounts;
```

I think that if it's not specified doctrine will not load accounts data from database until it's really requested, with getAccounts...

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. You fixed that so quickly ;)

Comment: Men you just save my nerves! Thx

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't avoid lazy loading, if you don't need it then it wouldn't get loaded.
If you need it just call it...foreach, iterator_to_array()...
You can even dump it with `dump(iterator_to_array($yourVar));`